# How do i split the web scraped column name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hey I'm actually doing a web scraping analysis on pokemon data. So i have this below code:

```
pokemon='https://pokemondb.net//pokedex/bulbasaur'
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(pokemon, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)[-2].T
tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
tables=tables.drop(tables.index[0])
tables
```

That gives me something like this:
[Columns with pokemon location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsOSx.png)

Now what i want is the column to split for different games for example, RedBlue would be Red and Blue separately with the same data for RedBlue being shown for Red and blue separate columns. I think i can do that when scraping the data but I don't know how to go about it.

I'm attaching below a screenshot of the html tags related to the data. I think the Red and blue can be split as there's a '&' between them. How do I do this?

[HTML tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILuKH.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should iterate per columns:

```
(Pdb) tables.columns
Index(['RedBlue', 'Yellow', 'GoldSilverCrystal', 'RubySapphire',
       'FireRedLeafGreen', 'Emerald', 'DiamondPearlPlatinum',
       'HeartGoldSoulSilver', 'BlackWhiteBlack 2White 2', 'XY',
       'Omega RubyAlpha Sapphire', 'SunMoon', 'Ultra SunUltra Moon',
       'Let's Go PikachuLet's Go Eevee', 'SwordShield'],
```

And create a special logic like:

```py
for column in tables.columns:
    if column = "RedBlue":
        # create new columns
```

As you don't have any special character separating the strings, is difficult to create a logic for all columns